# Saving image from multipart/form-data using AWS Lambda (Python)

Tags: python, aws-lambda, multipartform-data

I am using multipart/form-data with Ajax to send strings and upload a file. I am able to parse the strings somehow and I believe I am able to get the image file in string format as well but when I save the image to an S3 bucket and try to open it , it says "file format not supported".

Here is the HTML code:

```
      <div  class="form">
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
                <p class="contact"><label for="company">Company</label></p>
                    <input id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company Name" required="" tabindex="1" type="text" value="MyCompany">
                    <p class="contact"><label for="name">Driver Name</label></p>
                <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="First and last name" required="" tabindex="2" type="text" value="Alex">
                      <p class="contact"><label for="gender">Gender</label></p>
            <select class="select-style gender" name="gender" id="gender">
            <option value="m" selected="selected">Male</option>
            <option value="f">Female</option>
            <option value="others">Other</option>
            </select><br><br>

                        <p class="contact"><label for="vehicletype">Vehicle Type</label></p>
                        <select class="select-style gender" name="vehicletype" id="vtype">
                        <option value="car" selected="selected">Car</option>
                        <option value="truck">Truck</option>
                        <option value="bus">Bus</option>
                        </select><br><br>

                    <p class="contact"><label for="vehicleNo">Vehicle Registration Number</label></p>
                    <input id="vehicleNo" name="vehicleNo" placeholder="Vehicle Number" required="" type="text" value="PB03W1234">

          <p class="contact"><label for="phone">Mobile phone</label></p>
            <select name="Country_Code">
  <option value="volvo">Select Country Code  </option>
  <option value="+91" selected="selected">+91 - India </option>
</select>
<br>
 <br>           <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Mobile number" required="" type="text" required="" pattern="[0-9]{10}" value="9999999999"> <br>
        <p class="contact"><label for="phone">Photo</label></p>
            <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*"><br>
                <p class="contact"><label for="phone">Driving License </label></p>
            <input type="file" name="dl" accept="image/*"><br>
        <p class="contact"><label for="phone">Registration Certificate </label></p>
            <input type="file" name="rc" accept="image/*"><br>
            <input class="buttom" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Register" type="submit">

   </form>
```

Here is AJAX Call:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: API_ENDPOINT,
            type: 'POST',
            /*headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },*/
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            contentType: false,
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            // contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 600000,
            success: function (data) {

                $("#result").text(data);
                console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
                $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);

            },
            error: function (e) {

                $("#result").text(e.responseText);
                console.log("ERROR : ", e);
                $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);

            }
        });
```

and here is the Python Code with which I am trying to save the file:

```
import json
from cgi import parse_header, parse_multipart, FieldStorage
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
import boto3
import base64
import re

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('MyBucket1234')
path_test = '/tmp/output'         # temp path in lambda.

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    myEvent = event['body']
    for r in ((string2replace, ""), ('\r\n', ""), (abc, ""), ("name=", "")):
        myEvent = myEvent.replace(*r)


    myEvent = myEvent.replace('"*"', 'abc')

    resultStart = myEvent.find("Content-Type: image/png") + 23
    resultEnd = myEvent.find("dl") - 2

    data = myEvent[resultStart:resultEnd]  #This Give me start and end of Image File.



    key = "Image.png"          # assign filename to 'key' variable


 object = s3.Object('MyBucket1234', key)
    object.put(Body=data)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!'),
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
    }
```

From cloudwatch logs, I can see Event['body'] output like this:

```
'body': '------WebKitFormBoundaryz3PvAgjndyUmKY0W\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="company"\r\n\r\nMyCmp\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryz3PvAgjndyUmKY0W\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\r\n\r\nAlex\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryz3PvAgjndyUmKY0W\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="gender"\r\n\r\nm\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryz3PvAgjndyUmKY0W\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="vehicletype"\r\n\r\ncar\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryz3PvAgjndyUmKY0W\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="vehicleNo"\r\n\r\nDL03W1234\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryz3PvAgjndyUmKY0W\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Country_Code"\r\n\r\n+91\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryz3PvAgjndyUmKY0W\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="phone"\r\n\r\n8989898998\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryz3PvAgjndyUmKY0W\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="pic"; filename="Ansible_Logo.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n�PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00�\x00\x00\x00�\x08\x04\x00\x00\x00i7�@\x00\x00\x00\x04gAMA\x00\x00��\x0b�a\x05\x00\x00\x00\x01sRGB\x00��\x1c�\x00\x00\x00 cHRM\x00\x00z&\x00\x00��\x00\x00�\x00\x00\x00��\x00\x00u0\x00\x00�`\x00\x00:�\x00\x00\x17p��Q<\x00\x00\x00\x02bKGD\x00���̿\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x00H\x00\x00\x00H\x00F�k>\x00\x00\x0c\x1aIDATx��kpTE\x16�\x7f3y\x07H�\x11Bx�\x10] ��D\x14T\x1e\x05Z� �\x12\x05V,\x04�\x05|�b\x15\n"�Z��%*R\x08,�+�(��">\x11\x04Vむ\x08&D\t\x10 !\x04\x08\x10H&C���\x0c�ͼ2�^�N������G�����t�~\x04"� �\x08"� �\x08"�m�\x16���ĸsg~+\x04؉%�t:�J"-IB\x00(�I\x19e������5\x12�L&=�KoRI�\x05ͼ�8C\x15����Mle/%��:\x08��+C��~�b\x0f�\t��]|�Wl�ܭ#\x17)R\x18�2\x0eR�\x18H\x15la\x06}����Жɬ�Ґ��S\x1d{y�싍����Z�&�?���C��ǵ^�R*.���4a\x07S���߂)\x14\\`�ϥj�ӻi���"ӭ>p����7U�g}H��O��"��\to�vvY ~}SX@��f�F��"�\x05�,+�ܔj�\x0e\x0eX(~�W��˚N�\x17Y,~=\x05�Ii\n\x04\x0c�T�����i\x1en�{�]��\x17\x04\x07Ӊ\r��-YiF\x00�dH�t\x14��w��\x13>�cy�\x1a3�O�\x13"R&7��`+Y�"`(%f꿓8�\x1e[��\x19c���p�߆�͈o�ir\x0e52Č%8Ÿp����6C@\x0b�I��}�6C�wt���.�0W���KC�C~g�g8�hc�h\x0cQ�C\x0f3�E3�A�\t�3\x13��b\x1c�V�\x7f7~1���H�4D��4�F\x17O[�\x01Q�a��<�+�w\x19��耝Qt���;��\\���Bw��d�҅�\x12k�N�Z5�1�\\��&c��\x7f&WH�2�}�u���\x1f3�\x1bR��ę�/�?��[��2��\r[e\x00�X\x139�F��\x06p�r���"��r���L��9ç�Ѐ>�b1QLTžG9P�*5�2\x9c3\x1c@��\x0f�^1W�\x1d娻��r��oC�M�.�f�~�kC�\x01Iz��\x0e\x1f�q�7�;����\\ws�O��\n�\x13�j��Ռ�*�T����5w.���L\x03F��X�8x�N��\x060By�Ri��{�j\x18\x0e�l�\x11��\x17$ӯ\x01]̸�\x18�V����+\x07Y���D3�0=��F\x0b��\x7f�\n�8�*�k�+CX`fTp�^�Ԁhڙ1�w���\x7f�.��?�՝��\x00�:\x10�o�H/\x01Iff�R4��\x7f���Z�B�\x7fȸ!���\x13Я\x01���\x7f�\nۜ�\x07���g\x1cQ�Ʈ��))�$�\x12�\x1a\x10�\x14U\\\x1c/���R>W�u��Q�]�<�~\r0��=\x18��5�5��(��\x1bԹ�#ik� \t%\x01&�\x15�=\n��K����G�w�.e�%�{�\x04�p\x19�\x0e�ў\x162�AH���J\x07\x1e�d!�^\x02NQa�\x00�(�t��9��\x7f��tVu-��;ߓ~�\x1a@](\tkcl\x11L3\x15�\x11yA�e�\x14i¡E2D�j��\r��7��\x15T1>�\x04ı�\x08\x017�\x10H�d\x0bb���\x1b\r\x05��g�sߛ�F\x0b\'��\nNr[h\x1b�b��G�\n%�z%h+y�AX�Mw\x078A�R\x7f��\x7fҴ���\x120\x13�^\x02�����]\x1a���/R�� W��M�IJ_\n$Y/\x01{I\x0b-\x01\x7f��w\x12|�\x12�D�6�\x16%7K���2\x19)Q�JJU�|�^\x02��"�\x04�显Oj�\x11�\x05e�·�{�6\r\x05NyBR�E��c�d�Lo�z�H[��#`�Rh��\x10�>��\x7f5�\x06����\x1a�ҷV�P�\x1c�Y�G�x�I��[�\t�8\x1b��y��5\x01�\x017���4Iϲ��4��c\x03��(�]c*��+)�\x13����\x13Ћ��\r�|�\x06�{¬w�%\x13�\x0c��`�a\x1ds�\x18@��~�\x04��2%ȼ T9M�탂�IBp��1�\x08Q#�\rn\x12t��\x1e�\x05%D�<�C\x07\x06\x06G@�U+G3��\x1dl�qp�$>�~��R�A�\x12�\nff�I��! �9�5.� �\x08������j)h@@��o��B+w��m|}p�|�\x048�s��&\x1d�\x06\x14�n�\x00�\x0b��P����G\x00\x0e�����rՀ^�h@�\x04\x1e�:csi�PG\x197\x05Z�a�?��O>��@��"jX�/��\x15{��\x1d�}�\x12�\x1a�V\x19�\x03�r6p\x13�U��J`�$K�$5���\\���dS\x18\x17�k�\x19\x1e�.�����\x1co\x02�ױڊ\x0e�/$�j�f`I�g�\x00�\x1f��:��W�U�\x1f�\x18Ȟ0�\x7f�y��+�u�wq4L��0�\x11��B叄�\x18~C7�\x04b��7Tz\x01�w��� ��z��&Sn������A�,�������x�x\x0c?[�w���v+�\x12�X\x1bL��D:�\x0cZ҄ё�Bf\rβ�\x11��*\x1b��A\x0e\x1b��(�;�9�t.\x12td�\x05�\x07\'Y�Ц_�Zع���m�\x0c���\x7fDNS<5$�nr\x16���D\'�\x00o32�g\x04�,i\x0e�p+��^G-�r�<�`#�8B\x1b\u0530\x06Ѵ�j��A7.%�(�%���8{(`\x1b�ɧʊ�����6�%�L:�D�\nd���r�(��\x13\x1c����\x1d�iæ��k�\x11D\x10A\x04\x11D`�3�jd`\x03�,wt���8\x01�\\���쉖�#�\r���\x03�����/�k�I\x02PI\x11��Ei��ø�\x0f9���`�\x10�F\x15?�G��[�2������8zҗt�J���\x1f�\x1cԜ�R����\x1b)\'�Adv\x01\x9d\x1ew�\'�Z*(���Tr��̟U����4\\8��\x14�pp�y^�\x7f&�b���n�,�q�{�\'9�{�G"�����&���\x03N�($�,f3�C~�O�\x01�Y�r��6t �kØ�gP��\x17�\x1a;B\'\x1eb*�x�c+D �\x1d�c\x14�\x0c�Tb�\x15�8�CA\x10`g\x14�l�\x1f�X�u�>H5�ǘI�_E��$o�\x05��jod�p�S�y�\x7f2�%A�V�ӗ�,`��wQ�[\x03!�\x11�d\x0eь�y���lg\x12w�}���f�ɳ\x1fmة�&���*l�\x04c�\x03\x16;�.<�\x17|�Mt���\n6��.��\x14����\x1dgXL/Ɠ�;�b��E,vR�\x00����\x1cg�_-�E�jF�\x10���:�,\x07}7��h��T0\x08��*\x1e�>�\n�!��p���~� d�7�9K\x01\x7f�y���>��\x0c����^\x1c\x08k�f\x02&P\x17�\x08�2\x17�E%�Tr��F4�/}i�\x138Y�^rX���a\x19ݙ�L\x1e��m��\x14+\x18�mL\'��,��6���H.;�\x011��\x1a��\x00\x07�\x0eō�N\x0e��B\\@-y��?����]���h^����ԀD�\x1d\x1fS�#,��\x01�K7��\x18\'�\'\x08\r�����Wk���pƁ4�-�)gL0�\x06�\x1b�Lna\x07��#N擉�1>w2\np�g(�q\x06\x06l�\x05��\x19�1�� [�9��\x16�"��K�=el\n�_u�\'�\x162��b>e"[\x18F\x1c�\x078�`+���1[\x1fMG�UM\x08�\x08���6ڰcÎ\x1d;-\x19\x04\x14���|:o�8H\x1a�5�\x08Q��<�S����Q>\x01`;���D�\x19�V\r���hs���,f\x12��zڱ\x02\x07�ٍ�h�r\'NV{�\x00��*��t�\x06���-lf�WH�?�5��\x15�O\x1dc\x19ټ�u�\x06hN:%,��G���\x00Z�:��\x10���ä\x10�!��\x12�+E�a>]\x18�v�֣��\x19�x�Ņ�"��?\x1ee\x1d����\x1f���j�k-+�ˁ\x06w\x1cf?��_��a�"@x�Z&3�\t��\x16\x07kY�\x00�_3ҞC�<�z%�M\x05{4-3�tNQ�Q�42��QL\x0c��B\n���0\x05\x1c���J��#\x04�D\'��e٨��+N\x1cG\x06�\x11\x0ex�\x14[ҍT����b�pD��\x11D\x10A\x04\x11D\x10A\x04\x11D\x10A\x04n�\x1f�0P�\x1a4\x0f�\x00\x00\x00MtEXtcomment\x00File source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ansible_Logo.png��K\x00\x00\x00%tEXtdate:create\x002015-10-07T12:57:59+00:00\x1a�Í\x00\x00\x00%tEXtdate:modify\x002015-10-07T12:57:59+00:00k�{1\x00\x00\x00GtEXtsoftware\x00ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.orgo���\x00\x00\x00\x18tEXtThumb::Document::Pages\x001���/\x00\x00\x00\x18tEXtThumb::Image::height\x002002�\x16�\x00\x00\x00\x17tEXtThumb::Image::Width\x00200�&E4\x00\x00\x00\x19tEXtThumb::Mimetype\x00image/png?�VN\x00\x00\x00\x17tEXtThumb::MTime\x001444222679��\x15=\x00\x00\x00\x13tEXtThumb::Size\x002.04KBB��\r{\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND�B`�\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryz3PvAgjndyUmKY0W\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dl"; filename=""\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryz3PvAgjndyUmKY0W\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="rc"; filename=""\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryz3PvAgjndyUmKY0W--\r\n', 'isBase64Encoded': False}
```

I have been struggling with this from more than a week now. Please suggest something to unblock the situation.

Comment: And how about that *API* endpoint...

Comment: API End point is defined. It's not the complete code. It is defined as a variable API_ENDPOINT

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue. Two things are happening: 1) the image data is sandwiched inside a large string in the request body, and 2) the image data has been corrupted or converted somehow. I have checked multiple different character encodings and none of them are able to reproduce the image after it is sent through the ajax request. Were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Not Yet.. I tried few other methods but then I encountered other issues...

Comment: Are you able to solve this problem? I am facing the same issue where the image is always corrupted.